# Replace HTML <i> tags with colored text in Perl6

Tags: search, replace, colors, eval, raku

I get a string from a database with multiple  HTML tags and want to display the marked words with color in a terminal. I tried this with Perl6 but could not find a working solution. Following are steps I tried:

```
use v6;

use Terminal::ANSIColor;

my $str  = "Text mit einem <i>kursiven</i>  und noch einem <i>schrägen</i> Wort.";
my $str1 = "Text mit einem { colored( "kursiven" , 'blue') }  und noch einem { colored( "schrägen" , 'blue') }  Wort.";

say "\nOriginal String:";
say $str ~ "\n";

say "and how it should look like:";
say $str1 ~ "\n";

say "Var 01: Remove the tags in 2 steps:";
my $str_01 = $str.subst("<i>" , "" , :g).subst("</i>" , "" , :g);
say $str_01;
say "==> ok\n";

say "Var 02: Remove the tags with dynamic content:";
my $str_02 = $str.subst(/"<i>"(.*?)"</i>"/ , -> { $0 } , :g);
say $str_02;
say "==> ok with non greedy search\n";

say "Var 03: Turns static content into blue:";
my $str_03 = $str.subst(/"<i>kursiven</i>"/ , -> { colored( "kursiven" , 'blue') } , :g);
say $str_03;
say "==> nearly ok but second part not replaced\n";

say "Var 04: Trying something similar to Var 01:";
my $str_04 = $str.subst("<i>" , "\{ colored\( \"" , :g)
                 .subst("</i>" , "\" , 'blue'\) }" , :g);
say $str_04;
say "==> final String is ok but the \{ \} is just displayed and not executed !!\n";


say "Var 05: Should turn dynamic content into blue";
my $str_05 = $str.subst(/"<i>(.*?)</i>"/ , -> { colored( $0 , 'blue') } , :g);
say $str_05;
say "==> total fail\n";
```

Is it possible to do this in one step or does I have to first replace the tags and the text with a static placeholder and then replace this again?

Comment: Maybe s/eval/regex/ in the tags?

Answer (score 2):

```perl6
$str.subst(

    :global,

    /

        '<i>' ~ '</i>' # between these two tags:

            ( .*? )    # match any character non-greedily

    /,

    # replace each occurrence with the following
    Q:scalar[{ colored( "$0" , 'blue') }]

)
```

For anything more complex I would use a grammar combined with an actions class.

Comment: I get a warning "Use of Nil in string context ... " and it also gives no result. In order to get $0 as replacement I have to write -> { $0} . The same applys also for the function call to "colored". But it does not work for both.

Comment: @Brad-Gilbert, Nice answer. Please consider adding a sentence or two here in comments or in your answer about why you've used `Q:scalar[{ colored( "$0" , 'blue') }]` rather than just plain `{ colored( "$0" , 'blue') }`, as suggested by @user2944647.

Answer (score 2):

After playing with Brads answer I found the following working:

```
$str.subst(

    :global,

    /

        '<i>' ~ '</i>' # between these two tags:

            ( .*? )    # match any character non-greedily

    /,

    # replace each occurrence with the following
    { colored( "$0" , 'blue') }

)
```